# Iterating over a nested Linked List in another LL in C

Tags: c, linked-list, nested-lists

I know similar questions to this one have been asked, but I don't seem to be able to properly apply other cases to mine.

I have just recently started using C and this is an assignment for school so in-depth guidance is preferred over code.

I have a Linked List holding information about a file with the following struct:

```
struct node {
    char * word;
    int count;
    float freq;
    struct node *next;
}
```

Then I have another Linked List which has the previous list as a part of the data contained in its struct like so:

```
struct node2 {
    int file_fd;
    int word_count;
    struct node *wfd_fd;
    struct node2 *next;
}
```

I want to be able to iterate a function over the entirety of the wfd_fd structure I am pointing to while pulling information from the nested LL. For example, trying to add up the frequency of every word in a specific file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically iterating over nested lists is just using nested loops: One outer loop for the outer list, and then a loop nested inside for the nested list.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
// Outer loop for outer list
for (struct node2 *n2 = node2_head; n2 != NULL; n2 = n2->next)
{
    // Inner loop for inner list
    for (struct node *n = n2->wfd_fd; n != NULL; n = n->next)
    {
        // Do something with n->word...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are *n2 and *n just arbitrary pointers that I set to the structure I have already made, or are they from said structure?

Comment: @sbling I used the types shown in your example. The names of the variables can be anything that suite you, but I recommend something descriptive.